# cdk warning No routeTableId was provided to the subnet at 'PrivateSubnet1'

Tags: python-3.x, aws-cdk

I'm associating vpc to my lambda like this:

```
self.vpc = _ec2.Vpc.from_vpc_attributes(self, 'vpc', vpc_id=self.vpc_id,
                   availability_zones=['eu-west-1a', 'eu-west-1b', 'eu-west-1c'],
                   private_subnet_ids=[self.private_subnet_1, self.private_subnet_2,
                                                                    self.private_subnet_3])
```

Now when I tried to associate this vpc with my lambda it shows a warning:

```
No routeTableId was provided to the subnet at 'PrivateSubnet1'. Attempting to read its .routeTable.routeTableId will return null/undefined.
```

`routetableid` is optional as per documentation. So how can I get rid of this warning message?
Is there any methods can I use to find the lists of routtableid based on vpc and private subnets?

Answer (score 5):

This is annoying me as well.

In the vpc module in CDK there is [a piece of code which checks whether the Subnet object has a routeTableId](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-ec2/lib/vpc.ts#L2103) and if not, adds the warning message to the Annotation object of the Subnet Object.

I just raised an [upstream issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/19786) on github, let's see what the folks there say.

My suggestion is basically to get rid of the whole warning as it's only about a potential situation, in which case I would just have synth fail if it really occurs instead of warning everybody that it might potentially happen.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31471265)

Comment: Well, the asker is asking if there is any method. The answer is basically answering that there is no method and it is explaining why there is not.

Answer (score 0):

Are you defining the subnets in this stack itself or importing them ? There is a [routeTable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/Subnet.html#aws_cdk.aws_ec2.Subnet.route_table) attribute available on the subnet.

Having said that, are you getting the error during synth or deploy ? I have something similar on my end and was able to deploy the lambda in the vpc with just the below code.

```
_vpc = _ec2.Vpc.from_vpc_attributes(
            self, 
            "VPC",
            vpc_id = "vpc-13213",
            availability_zones = ['us-east-1a'],
            private_subnet_ids =  ["subnet-123213"],                    
        )
```

_lambda.Function(self,
"lambda",
handler="",
.......
vpc=_vpc
)

Comment: @cheezesI'm importing them already existing.....that means can be accessed via `self.private_subnet_1.route_table(self)` . I'm getting this warning during synth

Comment: This is exactly what my call is...but getting a warning message during synth

Comment: As long as the private_subnet_1 is a Subnet instance, you can do a .route_table